# yFiles BusRouter not collapsing edges

Tags: yfiles

Any ideas why yFiles bus router not collapsing edges?

Here is the code:

```
var router = new yfiles.router.BusRouter();
router.applyLayout(g_graphControl.graph);
```

And here is the screenshot:

[image]